# Storing boolean values in spring boot backend from android app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an android app from where I am trying to execute an item.

The item is executed on click of the checkbox and the repository in the spring back-end is updated with execution details.

Now I want to store the state of the checkbox also in the database. Eg. When the checkbox is checked, database should store it as true and false when the checkbox is unchecked .

Following is my code

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void ItemExecution(@RequestBody ItemExecution itemExecution {
        Item item = itemRepository.findOne(itemExecution.getItem().getId()));
        itemExecutionService.executeItem(itemExecution,item,itemExecution.isExecutionState());
    }
```

I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@609f7353; line: 10, column: 13]
```

Is this the right way to save a boolean value. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: For starters stop making your web layer transactional. Your service layer should be transactional. Also you are already passing in the `ItemExecution` so why are you also passing the boolean (which is already inside that object)? The exception seems like to hint that you are trying to send a list and not a boolean.

Comment: Even after removing the boolean I'm getting the same error

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace and the json string you are receiving.

Comment: As I stated in my first comment, the exception hints at the fact that you are trying to send a list of things but that is send wrong. So show the JSON and the actual model objects.